# Side by side on every screen resolution

Tags: asp.net, html, css

I have created a simple layout with Html and CSS which is like below :

**CSS**

```
.search-box{border:1px solid gray;padding:
5px;border-right:5px solid gray;padding-right:30px;
width:60%;font-size:14px;}

.search-box:focus{outline:none;}

.search-buton{background-color:gray; 
border:1px solid gray;padding:5px;font-size:14px;
cursor:pointer;color:#fff;width:10%;}

.search-buton:hover{background-color:#575E5B;border:1px solid #575E5B;}

.left{float:left; border:1px solid gray; width:68%;padding:10px;}

.right{float:right; border:1px solid gray;width:28%;padding:10px;}
```

**HTML**

```
  <div class="right">
      <input class="search-box" type="text" placeholder="ASP.NET MVC, JQuery, Ajax, etc." />
      <input class="search-buton" type="submit" value="Search" />
  </div>
  <div class="left">

  </div>    
  <div style="clear:both;"></div>
```

See the JSFiddle sample :

http://jsfiddle.net/tugberk/uuVuW/

As you can see, I am unable to see them smoothly. Some screen resolutions, it is perfect. But when I zoom in inside the browser, it is where the things get messy.

I thought about fixing this with CSS3 media queries but I am sure there is some CSS trick which solve this problem for me. Any thoughts?

> BTW, Any suggestion for the title of this question would be great. It is
>   not so creative I think.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use percentages for the padding as well because this affects the overall width

Here's an example:
http://jsfiddle.net/uuVuW/2/

This explains the box model:
http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html

Answer (score 0):

you can write like this :

```
  .left{
   border:1px solid gray;
   padding:10px;
   overflow:hidden;
   padding: 10px;
  }

 .right{
  float:right; 
  border:1px solid gray;
  width:28%;
  padding:10px;
  margin-left:20px
 }
```

check this http://jsfiddle.net/sandeep/uuVuW/3/